# How to compare charcter to new line in python

Tags: python

How can I compare a char to '\n' in python? Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
def grabInstructionsExecuted (str, beg):
    index = beg
    while str[index] != '\n'
        index += 1;
    return str[beg:index-1]
```

However, I get this error:

```
File "grabMIPS.py", line 7
    while str[index] != '\n'
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm new to python, this seems pretty basic but I can't get it to work. Thank you.

Comment: you need a colon `:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walking through the string character-by-character is slow and unnecessary.

```
def grabInstructionsExecuted (str, beg):
    return str[beg:].split('\n')[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the colon after while:

```
def grabInstructionsExecuted (str, beg):
    index = beg
    while str[index] != '\n':  # you need a colon here 
        index += 1;
    return str[beg:index-1]
```